# JBPM on docker with postgres and bytea instead of oid

Tags: postgresql, jbpm

We use JBPM server along with Postgres database under it. We have found out that our BLOBs are too fat (like more than 500GB). We assume that there are a lot of orphaned BLOBs. We have found out that we can switch from standard OID column types (for BLOBs) to bytea type. this is supported according to the official docs (link below).
However we can't even setup working JBPM instance when we try to apply that bytea column type.
Maybe anyone of you has some suggestions on it?

My setup:

- jboss/jbpm-server-full latest image
- container hosted on MS Azure App Service (linux type)
- we use docker compose to mount our volumes
- Postgres v11

official docs:

- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_process_automation_manager/7.7/html/managing_and_monitoring_kie_server/eap-data-source-add-proc

Problem:

- <host-url>/business-central returns 404

Comment: A `bytea` column has a limit of 1GB, so if you really have 500GB large objects, there is no way you can switch

Answer (score 1):

For jbpm to use bytea instead of oid, you need to create the DB schema in PostgreSQL by using the below ddl script:

https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm/blob/main/jbpm-db-scripts/src/main/resources/db/ddl-scripts/postgresql/postgresql-bytea-jbpm-schema.sql

By the default, OID will be used instead.

Also make sure to set the following system property for it to work properly:

```
org.kie.persistence.postgresql.useBytea=true
```

Hope it helps